# autoHideDuration is not working in Snackbar @material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, snackbar

I have used Snackbar from Material-ui to display an alert. I want to hide that Snackbar automatically after 5 seconds but `autoHideDuration` is not working .

```html
<Snackbar
  autoHideDuration={3000}
  open={true}
  ContentProps={{
    'aria-describedby': 'message-id',
  }}
  message={<span id="message-id"> Message </span>}
/>
```

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9hyZ.png)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You also have to implement the `onClose` method of the `Snackbar` component in order to make the timeout work.

Let's say the open status of the `Snackbar` is in your component state:

```
<Snackbar
  autoHideDuration={3000}
  open={this.state.open}
  ContentProps={{
    'aria-describedby': 'message-id',
  }}
  message={<span id="message-id"> Message </span>}
  onClose={() => this.setState({open: false})}
/>
```

Answer (score 6):

if you use functional component you can use react hooks and make it easy.

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === 'clickaway') {
      return;
    }
    setOpen(false);
};
    
<Snackbar autoHideDuration={6000} anchorOrigin={{ vertical: "top", horizontal: "right" }} open={open}  onClose={handleClose}>
   <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity="success>
      "Data Successfully Submitted"
   </Alert>
</Snackbar>
```

Comment: autoHide doesn't change state so this is actually creating an error for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `OnClose` property.

> (property) SnackbarProps.onClose?: ((event: Event |
> React.SyntheticEvent<any, Event>, reason: SnackbarCloseReason) =>
> void) | undefined

Callback fired when the component requests to be closed. Typically `onClose` is used to set state in the parent component, which is used to control the `Snackbar` `open` prop. The `reason` parameter can optionally be used to control the response to `onClose`, for example ignoring `clickaway`.

---

**Bonus information (related to the question):**
Also, you can specific reason of hiding by using `reason`:

@param `event` — The event source of the callback.

@param `reason` — Can be: "`timeout`" (autoHideDuration expired), "`clickaway`", or "`escapeKeyDown`".

```
const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    setNotify({
      ...notify,
      isOpen: false,
    });
  };
//...
<Snackbar
  onClose={handleClose}
  autoHideDuration={3000}
  open={true}
  ContentProps={{
    'aria-describedby': 'message-id',
  }}
  message={<span id="message-id"> Message </span>}
/>
```