# Reset autohide timer in Snackbar when Re-Rendering

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This is my snackbar component:

```
<Snackbar open={open}
  autoHideDuration={2000}
  onClose={handleClose}
  anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'center' }}>
    <SnackbarContent aria-describedby="message-id2"
      className={classes.snackbarStyleViaNestedContent}
      message={props.single_message[0]}
      action={action} />
</Snackbar>
```

I am calling it from another component which sends down data every 1-3 seconds randomly. I want to display a snackbar for 2 seconds everytime but am not able to do so since the autoHideDuration doesn't reset on every re-render. Is there a way I can reset the autoHideDuration timer on every re-render. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In the component's state, why don't you set the duration as a variable and re-assign it every time the value comes? That will cause the entire thing to re-render.

On a different note, if the previous notification is visible for 2 seconds (lets stay it starts at t1 and before t2 if another notification comes i.e. data comes than how should it behave? The old notification should hide and new one should come or both should be displayed together? This is because you refresh rate can go lower than the auto-hide duration (1-3 seconds).

Comment: Yes, if a new notification comes in the snackbar should display it and hide the old one. I have an array of values coming in that changes everytime (it holds the messages), and I use it on useEffect to re-render. The timer doesn't seem to reset though.

Comment: You can try by implementing onClose and toggle the open value there. Check this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55238278/autohideduration-is-not-working-in-snackbar-material-ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use a state and a javascript timeout, as I described in [your other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68791231/7507743).

```
var timeout;
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

<Button
  onClick={() => {
    setOpen(true);
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
      setOpen(false);
    }, 2000);
  }}
/>
<Snackbar
  open={open}
  onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
  message="Test snackbar"
/>
```

Just replace the button with the function you use to get the data