# Reset autoHideDuration timer on Snackbar when component updates

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, snackbar

I want the snackbar to timeout in 2 seconds only if the component doesn't update. If it updates I want the timer to reset if it hasn't reached 2 seconds yet.

```
useEffect(() => {
          setOpen(true)
        
    },[props.single_message])

        return(
           
        <div>
            {props.single_message.length !== 0 
                    ?
                    <Snackbar open={open} autoHideDuration={2000} 
                        onClose={() => setOpen(false)} 
                        anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'center' }} >
                            <SnackbarContent aria-describedby="message-id2"
                                className={classes.snackbarStyleViaNestedContent}
                                message={props.single_message[0]}
                                action={action}
                            />
                    </Snackbar>

                    :
                    null
            }
                
                
        </div>
    )
```

How can I reset the autoHideDuration on a component update if the autoHideDuration hasn't completed yet. If not possible with autoHideDuration, is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way would be something like this:

```
var timeout;
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

<Button
  onClick={() => {
    setOpen(true);
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
      setOpen(false);
    }, 2000);
  }}
/>
<Snackbar
  open={open}
  onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
  message="Test snackbar"
/>
```

However maybe something like this (using the current time) could work:

```
const [closeTime, setCloseTime] = useState(0);

<Button onClick={() => setCloseTime(Date.now() + 2000)} />
<Snackbar
  open={closeTime > Date.now()}
  onClose={() => setCloseTime(0)}
  message="Test snackbar"
/>
```

Comment: Awesome stuff. First part works just as intended.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use useEffect, here's what I did.

```
function Snacky({message}) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState();

  // This will display the snackbar and reset the timer whenever
  // the message prop changes to a non-falsy value
  useEffect(() => {
    setOpen(Boolean(message));
    // Clear any timeouts in progress
    clearTimeout(timer);

    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setOpen(false);
    }, 4000);
    setTimer(timeout);

    // Cleanup function
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [message]);

  return (
    <Snackbar
      open={open}
      message={message}
      action={
        <IconButton size="small" color="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
          <CloseIcon fontSize="small" />
        </IconButton>
      }
    />
  );
}
```